# How to get conditional data from elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

Currently, my ES data is similar to-

```
 {
      ..............
      ..............
      "centers" : [

        .................
        .................
        {
          "code" : "ABCA",
          "name": "first_code",
          "level" : 0
        },
        {
          "code" : "XYZX",
          "name": "second_code",
          "level" : 1
        },
        {
          "code" : "XYZX",
          "name": "third_code",
          "level" : -1
        },
        {
          "code" : "QWERTY",
          "name": "fourth_code",
          "level" : 2
        },
        .................
        .................

      ],
      ..............
      ..............
```

}

And I want to filter records with the condition like this-

filter records where **code = "ABCA" and code="XYZX"** with additional filter **code.level(ABCA) < code.level(XYZX)**

Expected O/p:

```
    {
      "code" : "ABCA",
      "name": "first_code",
      "level" : 0
    },
    {
      "code" : "XYZX",
      "name": "second_code",
      "level" : 1
    }
```

Is this possible?

Comment: there is no `code1` and `code2` fields, I guess you mean first and second element of your cenetrs array?

Comment: I have updated the question to resolve the confusion. Basically I need a filter with 2 conditions simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the [elasticsearch script query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-query.html) in order to achieve it,

Please refer [this SO answer](https://ritubhandaritechnicalside.wordpress.com/2018/03/27/elastic-search-compare-two-fields-in-the-document/) and [this blog](https://medium.com/@kuy/elasticsearch-matching-documents-having-a-field-of-multiple-choices-6d8a9dea4c9a) for more info and update if still you need help, please show query you tried and would be happy to help further.